Can reciting stotras truly give literal benefits as mentioned in their phala shruti?
In many Hindu scriptures, stotras are accompanied by a phala shruti (a declaration of benefits), which often promises significant results such as increased longevity, prosperity, or liberation.
Are such claims to be interpreted literally, or do they carry a more symbolic or psychological meaning?
To clarify, Do vibrations from the chanting alone gives us those benefits or should the benefits be attributed to the spiritual, mental, or lifestyle changes that arise from regular chanting of a stotra.

The phala-srutis mentioned are literal when the prayers are chanted with unflinching faith. However, manifestation of the boons requires the mercy of the Lord and cleansing away of one's sinful reactions. Leading a life as per the scriptures such as accepting initiation from a self-realized Guru, control over the senses, practicing austerities, etc. will expedite this process.
Here's an example of liberation from Shrimad Bhagavatam 10.51 where King Muchukunda had abundantly prayed (prārthitaḥ pracuraṁ) to Lord Krishna in a previous life.

सोऽहं तवानुग्रहार्थं गुहामेतामुपागत: ।
प्रार्थित: प्रचुरं पूर्वं त्वयाहं भक्तवत्सल: ॥ ४२ ॥

Since in the past you repeatedly prayed to Me, I have personally come
to this cave to show you mercy, for I am affectionately inclined to My
devotees.

When Krishna appears before Muchukunda, he asks for devotion unto the Lord and freedom from birth and death. Lord Krishna tells him that his remaining few karmas need to be cleansed before he can become fully liberated.

विचरस्व महीं कामं मय्यावेशितमानस: ।
अस्त्वेवं नित्यदा तुभ्यं भक्तिर्मय्यनपायिनी ॥ ६१ ॥

Wander this earth at will, with your mind fixed on Me. May you always
possess such unfailing devotion for Me.
क्षात्रधर्मस्थितो जन्तून् न्यवधीर्मृगयादिभि: ।
समाहितस्तत्तपसा जह्यघं मदुपाश्रित: ॥ ६२ ॥

Because you followed the principles of a kṣatriya, you killed living
beings while hunting and performing other duties. You must vanquish
the sins thus incurred by carefully executing penances while remaining
surrendered to Me.
जन्मन्यनन्तरे राजन् सर्वभूतसुहृत्तम: ।
भूत्वा द्विजवरस्त्वं वै मामुपैष्यसि केवलम् ॥ ६३ ॥

O King, in your very next life you will become an excellent brāhmaṇa,
the greatest well-wisher of all creatures, and certainly come to Me
alone.

Hence, fulfillment of desire as per the phala-sruti is guaranteed but requires patience.
